# Is there a way to hide the standard Facebook Chat Bar (without going offline)?

Tags: iframe, hide, minimize, facebook-chat

We're building a Facebook app that is basically a web integrated chat client on a canvas.

However, every time a message is entered or received in the app, a corresponding chat window pop up or notification occurs on the standard Facebook chat bar.

Is there a way to hide the chat bar or at the very least minimize the chat windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, in my understanding there is no api to pragmatically close or minimize chats within Facebook.com

Comment: Thanks! 
However, I'm looking at a few games like Candy Crush, Plants vs Zombies Adventures, The Wizard of Oz and more, while you're playing those games, the chat notifications remain minimized when received.  
Any idea how those games do it?